# How to resolve Access forbidden! error in codeigniter with xampp server

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, codeigniter-3

I am running a codeigniter project on xampp server it working fine with default controller but when I am trying to access other than default controller it is saying Access forbidden! You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

I have made changes in my `config.php` file as:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/passion';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

& this is my .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /http://localhost/passion/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in adnvance.

Comment: make sure  `.htaccess` should be in  base folder `passion`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Make sure `.htaccess` should be in folder `passion`*

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/passion/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

`.htaccess` file should be like:

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: worked for me. Thanks. Can you explain your solution,,